# Jupyter: printing all function arguments

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

There is a difference in how a function is printed in Jupyter to colab. If I print a DecisionTreeClassifier in Jupyter:

```
DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5, min_samples_leaf=105, min_samples_split=35)
```

it will only show certain arguments, whilst in colab all other arguments would also be printed, eg. class_weight, criterion, etc, even if set as `None` by default.

Is there anyway to force Jupyter to show all arguments?

Comment: Are you sure that this is a difference between Jupyter and colab, and not simply a difference in the scikit-learn version? If the version is different, maybe the print behavior changed...

Comment: @ATony you're right, for some reason it seems that from 0.22.2.post1 (colab) to (at least) 0.24.1 (local jupyter) this was changed. Looks like the method get_params is the easiest workaround. Cheers